# Posting back to current page in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am trying to create a few post methods on my page using Sitecore 7.2, unfortunately they are not working correctly and I can't seem to find out the best way to handle it.

I have two methods

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewApplicationsPage(){
        //do stuff
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewApplicationsPage(ApplicationPageViewModel model, (form parameters)){
        //do other stuff
        }
```

The page is /View-Application but when I use Html.BeginForm or Url.Action it points to "api/sitecore/ViewApplications/ViewApplicationsPage"

So I cant send my post data to the controller without building the string manually like `url + "?" + "&page=" pageValue + &count=" + countValue` etc.

Is there a way to reference the right area and pass the values a better way than constructing a string manually.

I have filters and pagination I need to apply on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RobertoBr said, you are getting your Http verbs backwards. An Http GET request will append your data as a series of key/value pairs inside of the url itself - which is why you were having to do some weird stringbuilding to hit your controller correctly. An Http POST request will send the data as key/value pairs inside the message body itself.

I would take a look at the method signature as well - I would think you'd be passing back either the viewmodel or a formcollection, but likely not both in a form submission type action.

Comment: Yeah just realized that this was the case I had my verbs backwards mentally. This fixes some of the problem unfortunately not the problem of hitting the controller directly with sitecore. instead of the /api/sitecore

Answer (score 3):

Isn't `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` inverted? I mean, you should expect the form values from a post not a get.